# My Ubuntu laptop has lost the ability to SSH (or IMAPS) outbound … other machines on the local net can do this. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, dns, iptables, imap

`ssh -vvv` shows nothing useful; just a timeout.

I can use a web browser (doing this right now), so DNS is OK.

It's not an iptables issue as I just flushed those to make sure .

Another machine on the local network (Macintosh) can do this with no problem (fortunately!)

Any ideas about this? This is driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't thinking about this to start, just noticing that my work laptop could connect and my Ubuntu personal couldn't.

But I had installed an update on the work laptop (a Macintosh) and hadn't brought its VPN back up and tried the SSH ... which timed out. I brought up the VPN and tried again ... and connected quickly.

Then I tried some tracerouting on port 22 and 993, where I was trying but failing to connect on my home laptop to an ssh host and an IMAP SSL server, respectively.

I found that they both eventually got there, but **slowly** ...

I installed ExpressVPN on my machine, got it connected and **bang** that was it.

I was shocked at how much faster it was; I had done some interviews during my last go-around of job hunts suggesting installing a VPN when Viasat internet wasn't fast enough, but it didn't seem to help.

I am connected now via a Cricket wifi hotspot, which is plenty fast to stream video (much faster than Viasat, in fact). But connecting to a New York IMAP SSL server: not so much.

Hope this is helpful for anybody else seeing such weirdness. I had this happening at the same time I was bringing up a new MX server for email being forwarded to Gmail and finding out how much more restrictive they've gotten since the last time I did this about 5 years ago. Quite a day!